# Please allow editing chat event descriptions

Tags: feature-request, chat

I can't figure out how to edit a chat event. [SF Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) is about to hold a “recommentation chat”. How can I change this to a more recommendable title?

I don't remember whether I was the one who created the event, but I'm a moderator on the associated site, so permissions shouldn't be an issue.

I could delete the event and create another one, but that would not be good for the people who subscribed to it and would be cheated out of a reminder.

Answer (score 10):

hmmm... there's not a convenient UI for that at the moment. I'll assume (for now) you want to fix the typo, so I'll hack that in at a lower level. I'll try to get a UI for this in too.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how much should be editable, arguably the times shouldn't be because that's what people subscribed for, but at least the description should be editable by the creator and ♦.

Comment: @Gilles - I think that makes sense

Comment: Can we get a status tag update on this?  We still don't have a UI for it.

Comment: [Requested again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147342/how-can-i-edit-event-details-scheduled-for-chat-room)

Comment: This is on the 6-8 years timeframe?