# How can I edit event details scheduled for chat room?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Please allow editing chat event descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91713/please-allow-editing-chat-event-descriptions)

We had an event on every Friday for the chat room [Indian Enthusiastic Programmers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13215/indian-enthusiastic-programmers). We were having technical discussions and solved more problems on event day.

I was absent last Friday. My fellow room owner deleted the event by mistake. So I have added a new event again. And I want to edit the details of the event. I want to change the event description.

How can I edit event details scheduled for a chat room? Can I get registered users for the old event to this new event again?